# product appears more than once in magento 1.9 pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, pagination

I have a problem in magento 1.9 in some categories some products that appear on the first page of pagination again Personal appear on the pages, replacing like this or next to some products. Has anyone ever had a similar problem?